# issue with php number_format()

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm having an issue with number_format.  When $val is over 1,000 in value, the $update will only SET a value of 1. If it is less than 1,00 in value, it will SET the correct value.

pmV is DECIMAL, 7,2.

I'm sure that I have just stared at this for too long and am missing something. What am I doing wrong? Please school me! ;)

```
// Set variables for received data
$id = strval($_GET['id']); // value is 1
$k = strval($_GET['k']); // value is 1
$dwt = strval($_GET['dwt']); // value is 25
$spot = "." . strval($_GET['spot']); // value is .70

//Query the database based on the variables received and 'echo' the results back
$sql="SELECT * FROM metals WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($id == 1){ // If we are calculating Gold, then add Karat into the calculation
        $num = ((($row['value']/20)*$k)*$dwt)*$spot;  //$row['value']=1200.01
    }
    else {  // If not, then don't
        $num = (($row['value']/20)*$dwt)*$spot;
    }
    $val = number_format($num,2,'.',',');
    echo $val;  // Send the value back to page --> Sending correct value - 1,050.01

    // Update the DB with the calculated PM amount
    $update="UPDATE totals SET pmV = $val WHERE id='1'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$update);  // UPDATES value of pmV to '1' instead of 1,050.01

    // Get the Diamond Value from the DB and Update the Total calculation
    $select="SELECT dV FROM totals WHERE id='1'";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con,$select);
        while($dv = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
            $val2 = $dv['dV']+$val;
            $sql4 = "UPDATE totals SET total = $val2 WHERE id='1'";
            $result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
            };
};

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're doing the calculations in PHP, rather than doing everything in a single `UPDATE` statement that joins `totals` with `metals`?

Comment: This is an internal calculator for pawn employees to calculate what value they will give for diamonds and precious metals. This php file needs to echo amount to give for the precious metal, as well as adding that amount to the db and re-calculating the total in a different column so that the page can also give a running total if diamonds were involved in the pawn.  I am all ears if there is a better way to accomplish this same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1,050.01` is not a valid number. It's a formatted string. So when you try to treat it like a number, things break.

To round a number to teo decimal places, try this:

```
$val = floor($num*100)/100;
```